# how to get the attribute of setter method of property in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-decorators, python-object

Please consider the below code

```
class DataMember():
  def __init__(self, **args):
     self.default = {"required" : False , "type" : "string" , "length": -1}
     self.default.update(args)
  def __call__(self , func):
     #Here I want to set the attribute to method 
     setattr(func , "__dbattr__" , self.default)
     def validate(obj , value):
        #some other code
        func(obj , value)
     return validate
```

This is my decorator method to decorate the setter method of property of other class, I want to set some attribute to the method. but it doesn't allow me.

I tried as below

```
class User(DbObject):
  def __init__(self):
      super(User , self)
      self._username = None
  @property
  def Name(self):
      return self._username

  @Name.setter
  @DataMember(length=100)
  def Name(self , value):
      self._username = value

 u = User()
 u.Name = "usernameofapp"
 print(u.Name)
 print(u.Name.__dbattr__)
```

Got the below error when ran this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "datatypevalidator.py", line 41, in <module>
print(u.Name.__dbattr__)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dbattr__'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I set some attribute to setter method.

Comment: @LevZakharov, There would be more property in User class and can have different DataMember decorator parameters, Then how I will access the attributes for each property separately, Please explain, I am a bit low in python

Comment: Could you remove the dependency on `DbObject` so one can actually run the example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK so there are three points of confusion here. Object identity, descriptor protocols and dynamic attributes.

First off, you are assigning `__dbattr__` to `func`.

```
def __call__(self , func): 
    func.__dbattr__ = self.default  # you don't need setattr
    def validate(obj , value):
        func(obj , value)
    return validate
```

But this is assigning the attribute to `func`, which is then only held as a member of `validate` which in turn replaces `func` in the class (this is what decorators do ultimately, replace one function with another). So by placing this data on `func`, we lose access to it (well without some serious hacky `__closure__` access). Instead, we should put the data on `validate`.

```
def __call__(self , func): 
    def validate(obj , value):
        # other code
        func(obj , value)
    validate.__dbattr__ = self.default
    return validate
```

---

Now, does `u.Name.__dbattr__` work? No, you still get the same error, but the data is now accessible. To find it, we need to understand python's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) which defines how properties work.

Read the linked article for a full explination but effectively, `@property` works by making an additional class with `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` methods which when you call `inst.property` what you actually do is call `inst.__class__.property.__get__(inst, inst.__class__)` (and similar for `inst.property = value --> __set__` and `del inst.property --> __del__`(). Each of these in turn call the `fget`, `fset` and `fdel` methods which are references to the methods you defined in the class.

So we can find your `__dbattr__` not on `u.Name` (which is the result of the `User.Name.__get__(u, User)` but on the `User.Name.fset` method itself! If you think about it (hard), this makes sense. This is the **method** you put it on. You didn't put it on the value of the result!

```
User.Name.fset.__dbattr__
Out[223]: {'length': 100, 'required': False, 'type': 'string'}
```

---

Right, so we can see this data exists, but it's not on the object we want. How do we get it onto that object? Well, it's actually quite simple.

```
def __call__(self , func):
    def validate(obj , value):
        # Set the attribute on the *value* we're going to pass to the setter
        value.__dbattr__ = self.default
        func(obj , value)
    return validate
```

This only works if ultimately the setter returns the value, but in your case it does.

```
# Using a custom string class (will explain later)
from collections import UserString

u = User()
u.Name = UserString('hello')
u.Name # --> 'hello'
u.Name.__dbattr__  # -->{'length': 100, 'required': False, 'type': 'string'}
```

---

You're probably wondering why I used a custom string class. Well if you use a basic string, you'll see the issue

```
u.Name = 'hello'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-238-1feeee60651f> in <module>()
----> 1 u.Name = 'hello'

<ipython-input-232-8529bc6984c8> in validate(obj, value)
      6 
      7         def validate(obj , value):
----> 8             value.__dbattr__ = self.default
      9             func(obj , value)
     10         return validate

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dbattr__'
```

`str` objects, like most in-built types in python, do not allow random attribute assignment like custom python classes (`collections.UserString` is a python class wrapper around string that does allow random assignment).

So ultimately, what you originally wanted was impossible with built-in strings but using a custom class allows you to do it.

Comment: Perfect and well explained answer.

Answer (score 4):

access `__dbattr__` is a bit tricky:

first, you need get the property object:

```
p = u.__class__.__dict__['Name']
```

then get back the setter function object, named `validate`, which is  defined inside `DataMember.__call__`:

```
setter_func = p.fset
```

then get back the underlying `User.Name(self , value)` function object from the closure of `setter_func`:

```
ori_func = setter_func.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

now you could access `__dbattr__`:

```
>>> ori_func.__dbattr__
{'required': False, 'type': 'string', 'length': 100}
```

but is that useful? I don't know. maybe you could just set `__dbattr__` on the `validate` function object that returned by `DataMember.__call__`, as other answers have pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the attribute on the *wrapper* function that is being returned by your decorator class's call method:

```
class DataMember():
  def __init__(self, **args):
     self.default = {"required" : False , "type" : "string" , "length": -1}
     self.default.update(args)
  def __call__(self , func):
     #Here I want to set the attribute to method
     def validate(obj , value):
        #some other code
        func(obj , value)
     setattr(validate , "__dbattr__" , self.default)
     return validate

class DbObject: pass

class User(DbObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(User , self)
        self._username = None
    @property
    def Name(self):
        return self._username

    @Name.setter
    @DataMember(length=100)
    def Name(self , value):
        self._username = value
```

But note, it is not a method, since there is a property on the class, it instances will only ever return a string, the one returned by the getter. To access the setter, you have to do it indirectly through the property, which is on the class:

```
u = User()
u.Name = "usernameofapp"
print(u.Name)
print(User.Name.fset.__dbattr__)
```

which prints:

```
usernameofapp
{'required': False, 'type': 'string', 'length': 100}
```